# What are the exact artifact coordinates for the JaCoCo Gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, jacoco, gradle-plugin

I'm in a corporate environment where an artifact repository manager is, unfortunately, still an utopian concept and is currently not possible to on-board to for many projects. This being said, you can probably imagine the amount complexity involved in on-boarding external artifacts. (I'm very familiar with artifact repository managers and how to use them and I'm even the project owner of an OSS one, so need to give me the lecture on [archiva](/questions/tagged/archiva), [artifactory](/questions/tagged/artifactory), [sonatype-nexus](/questions/tagged/sonatype-nexus), [strongbox](/questions/tagged/strongbox) and the likes. I get it, but it's not up to me).

Could somebody please tell me what the exact (Maven) artifact coordinates and/or URL are for the Gradle JaCoCo plugin, so that it could be manually downloaded and approved internally?

The Gradle documentation only defines it as:

```
plugins {
    id 'jacoco'
}
```

So I'm not quite sure what this maps to as artifact coordinates, in order to look it up on Maven Central, or Bintray.

Comment: The jacoco plugin is bundled with gradle itself. It doesn't need to be downloaded separately. Just like the java plugin, or the war plugin, etc.

Comment: Right, so this is a built-in one and that's why it doesn't have more coordinates? Is there a page in the Gradle wiki that explains any of this? (For example, in Maven all plugins without `groupId` coordinates, fallback to `org.apache.maven.plugins`).

Comment: @JBNizet: Also, we're using Gradle 4.2.x and 4.10.x across our projects. When was this made a part of the Gradle distribution? Do these versions include it?

Comment: Could you please add this as an answer, so I can accept it? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Again, it's bundled with gradle. So it doesn't have any GAV, because it doesn't exist as a standalone plugin. You won't find it in the Maven repository, becuase it's part of gradle itself. Here's its documentation for gradle 4.2: https://docs.gradle.org/4.2/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html and for gradle 4.10: https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html. You should really upgrade. 4.2 and 4.10 are quite old versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's bundled with gradle. So it doesn't have any GAV, because it doesn't exist as a standalone plugin. You won't find it in the Maven repository, because it's part of gradle itself.

Here's its documentation for gradle 4.2: https://docs.gradle.org/4.2/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html and for gradle 4.10: https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html.

You should really upgrade. 4.2 and 4.10 are quite old versions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, we really should upgrade. However, we're going to upgrade to 6.0 first and, like the artifact repository manager, this is something which won't happen as quickly as we'd like.